# Automatically update from and to range values when editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, devexpress

I have a list of From and TO range values as like below in a devexpress grid.

```
From    To  
 1      100 
101     200  
201     300
```

When editing 100 to 80 need to update 101 to 81 automatically using c#. Only To date is editable.

Could you please anyone suggest how to do that.

Comment: What have you tried...?

Comment: What is the datasource of the grid, ie. what object structure is the displayed data stored in?

Comment: directly binding list<objects> as data source to grid.